# How to use wc_customer_bought_product function to check if customer bought product in an array

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, shortcode

First of all, I am a beginner and new to php so please forgive my ignorance. I asked my first question on stackoverflow today and somebody was kind enough to provide a great solution, so I am giving this another try.

I am trying to use a function to check if a customer bought a product inside an array of product ids as in his account pages when logged in I need to display a different menu if he bought product from array A or product from array B, array C, you get it. I would like to create a different function for each array of product ids and associate it with a different shortcode.

I have found the wc_customer_bought_product_function in the woocommerce functions reference, which is written like this :

```
/**
* Checks if a user (by email) has bought an item
*
* @access public
* @param string $customer_email
* @param int $user_id
* @param int $product_id
* @return bool
*/
function wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id, $product_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
 
    $emails = array();

    if ( $user_id ) {
        $user     = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
        $emails[] = $user->user_email;
    }

    if ( is_email( $customer_email ) ) {
        $emails[] = $customer_email;
    }

    if ( sizeof( $emails ) == 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare( "
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS itemmeta ON order_items.order_item_id = itemmeta.order_item_id
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS postmeta ON order_items.order_id = postmeta.post_id
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
            WHERE
            posts.post_status IN ( 'wc-completed', 'wc-processing' ) AND
            itemmeta.meta_value  = %s AND
            itemmeta.meta_key    IN ( '_variation_id', '_product_id' ) AND
            postmeta.meta_key    IN ( '_billing_email', '_customer_user' ) AND
            (
                postmeta.meta_value  IN ( '" . implode( "','", array_unique( $emails ) ) . "' ) OR
                (
                    postmeta.meta_value = %s AND
                    postmeta.meta_value > 0
                )
            )
         ", $product_id, $user_id
      )
   );
}
```

So I tried to use it to achieve what I wanted by transforming just the last parameter:

```
// Create function to check if client bought a product from array A
function check_is_category_A_customer()
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $customer_email = $current_user->email;

    if (wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id, $product_id=array ('2258', '2253',     
'2242')))

        return true;

    return false;
}

// Create shortcode to display menu for customers cat A
add_shortcode('CATA','check_cat_bought_A');
function check_cat_bought_A($atts,$content=""){
    if( check_is_category_A_customer() ){
        return do_shortcode($content);
    }
}
```

But it did not work. When I use the shortcode the menu no longer appears, but it does not show once I bought a product which id is in the array.

I tried this version of the function based on another example:

```
function check_is_category_A_customer()
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $customer_email = $current_user->email;

    if ( '' !=wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id, $product_id=array ('2258',    
'2253', '2242'), true))

        return true;

    return false;
}
```

But that did not work either. The shortcode no longer has effect, the menu appears in all situations.

I wrote this using different functions I took as models and information I stumbled upon, and I probably made terrible mistakes, because it is not working. If someone has any idea of what I did wrong or how to achieve this goal differently, that would be a huge help! Thank you.

Comment: btw: You should accept the answer given to the earlier question (click on the tick symbol)

Comment: Done - I wish I could be able to do the same on this question ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
function check_is_category_A_customer(array $product_ids)
{
    $product_ids= array ('2258','2253','2242');//for testing
    global $woocommerce;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $current_user= wp_get_current_user();
    $customer_email = $current_user->email;


    foreach($product_ids as $item):
        if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id, $item) )
           return true;
    endforeach; 

    return false;
}
```

You were not setting the $current_user object, see above for the correction.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it but unfortunately it does not work. The menu remains displayed wether the customer has bought a product or not, and no matter the product id of the item bought if a purchase has been made. I must be missing something else :(

Comment: updated the above, but if its not working try passing 1 product id at a time

Comment: Thank you for following-up on this :) I did try the last corrected version, it made the menu disappear, but not appear once one of the products in the array was bought. I tried leaving only one product id, it worked. But unfortunately creating one function and one shortcode for each product id is not gonna work, I need to be able to use the array, or a category id, but that is not one of the initial parameters of the function.

Comment: Or as a last resort maybe I could create a function using this model for each product id but associate a shortcode with multiple functions, but I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: updated the simple answer above, its not really efficient as it does 3 database queries but you are stuck using the original function which only checks if they bought all products rather than any product. You can eventually redo the woo function but thats a sql question :)

Comment: So... my answer is actually not so good, I spoke too fast, it works but I must have forgotten to close something althought I can't figure out what because the page keeps loading and this disturbs the load of other pages too outside the my account, as a request keeps being processed by the browser (any ideas?)

Comment: I just tried your updated answer but it generates a blank page when logging in a customer account where the shortcode is used :(

Comment: Edited my answer, I thought the semicolons between each if and elseif statement were not mandatory but their absence seems to be what was causing the problem of the page that kept loading. I added them, tried it again and it seems to work now.

Comment: true that. I dont see how you would get a blank page though all the function returns is true or false...maybe turn on php errors if they are off?, save you a lot of trouble! But well done on getting the above working.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure of what happened with the last function you gave me, I will test it again over the weekend and keep you posted on the results. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

So David helped me get on the right track and I should have known how to pass 1 product id at a time inside the same function but I didn't.

After some research and study, I wrote a new function using else if statements for each product id, tested it, and so far it is working.

So, even if using an array or a category id would have been more practical (but I don't know how to do it, yet) I am sharing this solution for other people who might wanna achieve the same goal :

```
// Create function to check if client bought a product from array A
function check_is_category_A_customer()
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $current_user= wp_get_current_user();
    $customer_email = $current_user->email;

    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id,'2258')) {
        return true;
    } else if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id,'2253')) {
        return true;
    } else if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id,'2242')) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// Create shortcode to display menu for customers cat A
add_shortcode('CATA','check_cat_bought_A');
function check_cat_bought_A($atts,$content=""){
    if( check_is_category_A_customer() ){
        return do_shortcode($content);
    }
}
```

Thanks again to David for pointing the direction :) Of course if someone has a better solution, or sees any mistakes in this, please speak up.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this and it worked:

```
function has_bought_items($product_ids)
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $customer_email = $current_user->email;
    $ex = false;
    
    foreach($product_ids as $item):
        if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id, $item) )
            $ex = true;
    endforeach; 
    return $ex;
}
```